# Сложить значение со списком

Tags: python, list

Как сложить значение `[100]` c `[60.0, 90.0, -40.0, 40.0, -120.0]`, чтобы получить `[160.0, 190.0, 60.0, 140.0, -20.0]`

Comment: вы нам тут, что домашку пишите? читайте правила оформления вопросов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Списковое сокращение, например:

```
[x + 100 for x in [60.0, 90.0, -40.0, 40.0, -120.0]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Векторные/матричные операции проще всего делать в Numpy:

```
In [38]: a = np.array([60.0, 90.0, -40.0, 40.0, -120.0])

In [39]: b = np.array([100])

In [40]: a + b
Out[40]: array([160., 190.,  60., 140., -20.])
```

PS для больших массивов (1000+ элементов) это будет работать гораздо быстрее по сравнению с использованием циклов в *Vanilla Python*.

Comment: можно написать просто `b = 100`

Comment: Ради интереса потестил сейчас - `numpy` в 200 раз быстрее это делает. Я помнил, что быстрее, но что настолько...

Comment: @Danis, конечно можно, но автор вопроса явно указал `[100]`)

Comment: @CrazyElf, попробуйте для списка из 5-10 элементов - Numpy может оказаться медленнее для маленьких списков)

Comment: @MaxU Даже и для маленьких он быстрее, хотя и не настолько. Впрочем, там уже `timeit` начинает на кэширование ругаться и результаты не стабильные. Вот от 1000 элементов прям в 200 раз стабильно в колабе.

Comment: @CrazyElf, у меня для списка из 5ти элементов ваше решение занимает: `1.02 µs ± 21.7 ns`, а мое - `2.57 µs ± 41.6 ns` :)

Comment: @MaxU Видимо зря я `timeit` использовал, похоже что-то где-то и правда дико кэшируется, просто `time` показывает, что на <1000 выгоды от `numpy` уже и нет )

Comment: @CrazyElf, я тоже `%timeit` замеры делал - он гораздо аккуратнее